# How to find the process id for the app instance created by "open" command

Tags: command-line

When I programmerly do `open -F -W -n -g -a /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari https://kernel.org`, I got back the process of `open` and its pid 93930.

But that's not the process (93931) of newly created Safari instance itself.

```
huocp 93931   0.0  1.9  6047904 160240   ??  S    11:55am   0:04.39 /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
huocp 93930   0.0  0.1  4340272  12212 s004  S+   11:55am   0:00.07 open -F -W -n -g -a /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari https://kernel.org
```

Now I have no way to close the Safari process programmerly. I can close the `open` process programmerly by killing 93930, but it leaves 93931 running.

So the question is: is there a way to get the pid of the application instance created by `open` command?

93931 (safari) is not even a child process of 93930 (open), I tried with pstree command.

Comment: Just an FWI, `open -FWnga Safari https://kernel.org` does the same thing as the _command_ you've shown, no need to draw it out the way you have. If you're looking to close the last opened occurrence of Safari, then this will do it: `kill -nx Safari` However, the next time you use the aforementioned `open` _command_, the `-F` _option_ will be ignored. In other words, the next time there will be two tabs for `https://kernel.org`.

Comment: @user3439894 the mac kill is bsd version, it seems doesn't know about `-nx`, but pgrep does the trick.

Comment: `pkill -nx Safari` will do it. `kill` was a typo on my part, which I missed when copying it from Terminal after testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389495/how-to-get-the-process-id-pid-of-an-app-launched-using-open-command-on-osx)

If you're programmatically doing this, one way to get the opened app's pid (subsequently using it to kill the process) is to get the grep the output of `ps 
aux` passing it the application's name.

```
ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -I <AppName> | sort -rn | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Basically, pipe the output of the `ps aux` command through grep and sort it based on the value of the start time column.

As pointed by @user3439894 below, there's an easier way without the above rigmarole.

```
pgrep -nx Safari
```

returns the PID of the last opened instance of Safari and

```
pkill -nx Safari
```

kills the last opened instance of Safari.

Comment: Thx! But that solution is not good enough, I have multiple safari instance running. The `open -n` will create a new safari instance which is the only one I want to kill.

Comment: There is absolutely no need whatsoever to go to such rigmarole with the compound command you've shown! E.g. `pgrep -nx Safari` does the same thing without the rigmarole. Additionally, if the goal is to close the last opened occurrence of e.g. Safari, then `kill -nx Safari` does it.

Comment: Oh nice. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The answer needs to be updated. kill on mac doesn't know about `-nx`, have to use pgrep to find out pid first.

Comment: @huocp, `pkill -nx Safari` will do it. `kill` was a typo on my part, which I missed when copying it from Terminal after testing.